# Include actual error in SP2013 error page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, asp.net

SharePoint 2013 gave us a wonderfully useful new error page that looks like this:

[image]

As any 2013 admins know, clicking the "Technical Details" link just gives you a correlation ID that you have to track down in the server logs. I'd like to either customize this page or create my own page that shows the actual error message - the same one you'd find in the ULS log when you track down the correlation ID and dig through about a hundred other errors that occurred at the same second, and that's AFTER you figure out which server it happened on.

**How can I embed the actual ASP.Net error into this default page, or a custom one?**